# TortoiseSVN - easier way to code review multiple revisions simultaneously?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I need to code review across multiple revisions. We have a ticket system, of course, and a single ticket might have a lot of commits.

In TortoiseSVN show log I can filter to the revisions I want to review. I can select all the revisions, and in the bottom pane I see the distinct list of files. If a file has only been modified, if I double click on that file I can view the change in my favorite diff program, so far so good.

Here's the issue. If a file is both added and modified within the range of selected tickets I selected, then double clicking that file in the svn log window gives an error. There might be 15 such files, and it's a pain to manually review those, across every revision, one by one.

Is there a convenient way to see how each file changed across a range of revisions even if a file was added then modified within those revisions?

Comment: Just verified that this question is [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - it concerns *software tools commonly used by programmers*.